# Checking Permutation/Combination Understanding

Tags: proof-verification, permutations, combinations

I'm heading into Finals week, and want to make sure I've got permutations/combinations solid. If you wouldn't mind looking over my answers and letting me know of any mistakes, I would be extremely grateful! :)

[image]

a) $8^5 = 32768$

b) $P(8,5) = 6720$

c) $P(6,3) = 120$

d) $8^4 + 8^4 + 8^2 = 8256$

e) $8! = 40320$

f) $5! = 120$

g) $2 * 6! = 1440$

Do these all look correct?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts a, b, c, and e are correct.

> d.  Strings are six letters, either starts with the substring 'ab' or ends with substring 'gh' or both, letters can be repeated.

The number of substrings that start with 'ab' is $8^4$ since we can fill each of the last four positions with any of the eight letters.

The number of substrings that start with 'ab' is also $8^4$ since we can fill each of the first four positions with any of the eight letters.

Notice that if we add the number of substrings that begin with 'ab' to the number that end with 'gh', we have counted those that both begin with 'ab' and end with 'gh' twice.  However, we only want to count them once.  Therefore, we must subtract the number of substrings that begin with 'ab' and end with 'gh' from the total.

The number of substrings that start with 'ab' and end with 'gh' is $8^2$ since we can fill the middle two positions of the string with any of the eight letters.

Hence, the number of substrings that begin with 'ab' or end with 'gh' is 
$$8^4 + 8^4 - 8^2$$

By adding $8^2$ to $8^4 + 8^4$, you counted strings that begin with 'ab' and end with 'gh' three times.

> f.  Strings that contain all eight letters exactly once and contain the substring 'bag'.

We have six objects to arrange.  They are: 'bag', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h'.  They can be arranged in $6!$ orders.

Alternatively, observe that since the string 'bag' has length $3$, the string must begin in one of the first six positions.  Once the string 'bag' has been placed, the remaining letters can be arranged in the remaining five positions in $5!$ orders.  Hence, the number of such arrangements is $6 \cdot 5! = 6!$.

It appears that you overlooked the fact that the string 'bag' could begin in any of the first six positions.

> g.  Strings that contain all eight letters exactly once and the letters 'a' and 'b' are adjacent to each other.

Place the letters 'a' and 'b' in a box.  We now have seven objects to arrange, the box and each of the six remaining letters.  The seven letters can be arranged in $7!$ orders.  The letters 'a' and 'b' can be arranged within the box in $2!$ orders.  Therefore, the number of such arrangements is 
$$7!2!$$
Alternatively, choose whether to use 'ab' or 'ba'.  Since the string 'ab' or 'ba' has length $2$, it must begin in one of the first seven positions.  Once its position has been chosen, the remaining six letters can be placed in the remaining six positions in $6!$ orders.  Hence, the number of permissible arrangements is 
$$2 \cdot 7 \cdot 6! = 2 \cdot 7!$$

It appears you did not consider in which of the seven places the string 'ab' or 'ba' would begin.